# count comments associated with post

Tags: laravel

I have two comments associated with a post, but the code to count the comments associated with the posts shows "1". Do you know why?

code to count the comments:

```
    $commentsCount= Post::with('comments')->count();
```

A post can have multiple comments, a comment is associated with a post.

Comment model:

```
public function post(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

Post model:

```
public function comments(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'post_id');
}
```

Do you know why?

Comment: I strongly suspect you'll need more code than that to get the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling with will eager load the comments onto the Post model but still only return one Post object.

You need to call comments on a post object to get a collection back that you can count.

Judging by the code you have if you do something along the lines of

```
$post = Post::find(1);
$commentsCount = $post->comments->count();
```

You should get what you are looking for.